Updating current row with its previous row value in select statements
I have a table and it has a varchar column. Its data is as shown below
**Car_Type**
Maruti - Alto
null - Breeza
null - Scross
null - Eritga
Tata - Nano
null - Nexon
null - Altroz
Hundai - Creta
null - i20

I need the output data like from the above data like as shown below.
**Car_Type**
Maruti - Alto
Maruti - Breeza
Maruti - Scross
Maruti - Eritga
Tata - Nano
Tata - Nexon
Tata - Altroz
Hundai - Creta
Hundai - i20

Please help me with the query. I tried with Lead and Lag but i am not able to get the data as expected.

You can't, as there's no column which represents rows order. It is more than clear if you have to do it using a pencil and a paper, but - without some other column (such as timestamp, sequence ID and similar), nope.

Assuming you do have another column to order by, see this similar question for how to solve this general problem with the analytical/window function last_value

In my view if you want this as per your requirement there should be two tables with relation
T1 manufacturer  and T2 model

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
